# How to bind polymer template dom-repeat using promise object?

Tags: javascript, promise, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

i trying to bind dropdown values using function inside this making call to firestore then i am returning value using promise

HTML

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_modOptsArry(item.modKey)}}" as="opt">
     <paper-item value="{{opt.$key}}">{{opt.obj.val}}</paper-item>
</template>
```

JavaScript

```
_modOptsArry(modeKey) { 
    let opts = [];
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("record").doc("s1").collection("class").orderBy('o').onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
            // let opts = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) { 
                var model = doc.data(); 
                opts.push({ $key: doc.id, obj: { val: model.nm } });
            });
            resolve(opts); 
        })
    })
    promise.then(function (result) {
        return Promise.resolve(result); // Here i am returning array but in the dom-repeat it not binding values because it is returning Promise Object My Array is there inside this Promise object. how to resolve this problem..
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a function looking something like this

```
getDropdownItems(props, item) {
    if (!this.props[item])
        this._modOptsArry(item);
    return this.props[item]
}
```

Let your `_mopOptsArry` method assign the result to `this.props[item]`; And then notify object. Like this:

```
this.props[item] = yourResultArray;
this.notifyPath('props.' + item);
```

Have a property called `props` with a value of `{}`

Then in your html, instead of calling `this._modOptsArry`; Call `[[getDropdownItems(props.*, item.modkey)]]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeremy, I can assign a value to the property and use it but here I am binding UI completely dynamic. I am binding same UI element multiple times in the UI if I am referring same property in all the place all the elements will get override with this property value, that's why I am using return method so that for each element i can bind unique values..

Comment: Hi @RajT please let me know if the solution in the edit worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this:

```
_modOptsArry() { 
    let opts = []
    const that = this
    firebase.firestore().collection("record").doc("s1").collection("class").orderBy('o').onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) { 
            var model = doc.data()
            opts.push({ $key: doc.id, obj: { val: model.nm } })
        })
        that.set('myArray', opts)
    })
}
```

And just bind myArray to the dom-repeat template

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{myArray}}" as="opt">
     <paper-item value="{{opt.$key}}">{{opt.obj.val}}</paper-item>
</template>
```

Comment: I can't do this because I am using this functions for dynamic fields in a one form I may bind 10 dynamic dropdowns based on element type so I can't use one scope for 10 dropdowns based on key all the drop-down values will change, that's why I am trying to return.. one more person also answered  for them also i have commented same..

Comment: In what way is your form "dynamic"? Because the solution I provided would be suited for any situations I can think of and it is dynamic. What does your "items" depend on?